# Pass list from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

From my controller I'm passing a list type view model. But I can't get of model items in the view. Please help!

Controller:

```
public List<EmployeeNameViewModel> GetDetail()
{
    var employee = context.Employees
                          .Select(x => new EmployeeNameViewModel()
                                           {
                                               Id = x.Id,
                                               Name = x.Name,
                                               SurName =  x.SurName,
                                               Project = x.Projects.SingleOrDefault()
                                           }) ;
           
    return employee.ToList<EmployeeNameViewModel>();
}
```

View model:

```
public class EmployeeNameViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }

    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<EmployeeNameViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
       <li>
           @item.Name
       </li>
}
```

If the code is running, the result looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mustafa",
        "surName": "Test",
        "project": { "projectId": 1,
                     "employeeId": 1,
                     "name": "Test Project",
                     "plannedStart": "2023-04-07T22:30:00",
                     "plannedFinish": "2023-04-30T22:30:00",
                     "employee": null
                  }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "TesterEmployee",
        "surName": "San",
        "project": { "projectId": 2,
                     "employeeId": 2,
                     "name": "WebAppProject",
                     "plannedStart": "2023-04-07T23:02:00",
                     "plannedFinish": "2023-11-07T23:02:00",
                     "employee": null
                    }
    }
]
```

I want to reach my true point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render a view it is necessary to use `return View()`, like in the following code:

```cs
public IActionResult GetDetail()
{
    var employee = context.Employees
        .Select(x => new EmployeeNameViewModel()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            SurName = x.SurName,
            Project = x.Projects.SingleOrDefault()
        }) ;   
     return View(employee.ToList());
}
```

---

For more information see [How controllers specify views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0#how-controllers-specify-views)